# Not getting any response in Jmeter after certain user count. Is it server issue or client machine where we are running JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running the load testing for 10 APIs for 200 concurrent users in Jmeter. But after 190 users I am not getting any response and there is no indication is Jmeter and nothing happens. So, used timeout for requests and it fails after the timeout. Also checked the memory and cpu utilization everything is around 60-70%. Want to know is server failed to respond or is machine where we are running Jmeter needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If you run tests up to 190 users without issues and the errors start occur only with 190+ I would assume that the server gets overloaded.

Also failure of the server to respond completely might indicate that the server has died and you should identify where it started experiencing problems, so called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)

So I would recommend starting with 1 virtual user and [gradually increasing the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) at the same time looking at the following charts:

- [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
- [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/)
- [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)

At the beginning phase most probably the number of transactions per second will be growing as the number of users grow and response time will remain the same. But at some point you will see that the number of transactions per second will stop increasing or even go down and response time will go up. The number of users just before this happens is the maximum number of users your system can handle.